# Using a jenkins managed npmrc file in a jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, npm, pipeline

I have a project where the .npmrc file contains auth credentials to install from a private repository. Due to this, we are not able to commit this .npmrc file to the repo. Each user has their own copy of the file with their own credentials in their local **~/users/%USER%/.npmrc** in which the project will read these global parameters.

The issue is building the project in jenkins fails at npmIntall due to this. I have tried to add an npmrc file like:

Manage Jenkins > Managed Files > Custom File. And then create the npmrc file.

Go to the jenkins build configurations > Build environment > Provide configuration files.
This let me choose the file. For the target I wanted this in the root (I assume) so target is just .npmrc (I have also tested ${WORKSPACE}/.npmrc)

Am I missing a step here? Should this not provide the build with the file?

Extra info, I found a plugin to help manage this called pipeline-npm. But my jenkins version is not compatible with the plugin so I must find another way. This seems like a VERY common situation so I figured the solution would be straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: All steps you did looks correct.  You can add step `sh 'cat ${WORKSPACE}/.npmrc'` to check the `.npmrc` existence and its content.